# В Xcode 9.4.1 при компиляции с RestKit, ошибка swift: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, swift4, компоновщик, ios11, restkit

Доброго времени суток! В Xcode 9.4.1 при компиляции проекта на Свифт выдает ошибку:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

При дальнейшем рассмотрении выдает следующую картину:

> ld: /Users/apple/Desktop/SeeFood/SeeFood/RestKit.framework/RestKit compiled with older version of Swift language (4.0) than previous files (unknown ABI version 0x06) file '/Users/apple/Desktop/SeeFood/SeeFood/RestKit.framework/RestKit' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Вот все изображение ошибки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я могу судить, то RestKit компилировался с более старой версией Свифт. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную проблему!

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в настройках проекта выставить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так там и стоит "Swift 4.1"

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы Вам помочь, я решил воспроизвести данную проблему на своей машине. У меня Xcode 9.4.1, в нём я создал проект на базе Swift 4.1. Далее я установил RestKit 0.27.2 с помощью CocoaPods, после чего добавил данную библиотеку в свой проект. Накидал простейший код для проверки работоспособности всех компонентов, всё собралось и запустилось без проблем.

Обновите RestKit в Вашем проекте и убедитесь в актуальности проблемы.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ так и сделаю!